# WPF Cancel Button

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, button

I am working on a WPF Application. One of my Windows has a Button called "Cancel" with its `IsCancel=true`. I need to show a message box with Yes/No when the user clicks Cancel or presses `ESCAPE` Key. If the user click Yes, the Window should continue closing but if the user clicks No, it should not close the form but continue the regular operation with the Window opened. How can I do so? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this will help you

```
void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(
            "msg", 
            "title", 
            MessageBoxButton.YesNo, 
            MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
        {
            // If user doesn't want to close, cancel closure
            e.Cancel = true;
        }        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can handle it in `WindowClosing` enent.

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx). There is an example very close to yours.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var Ok = MessageBox.Show("Are you want to Close", "WPF Application", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Information);

            if (Ok == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {

            }
```

Comment: Well thats the question! What to do for `No`?

Comment: Did that using `e.Cancel=True` in the NO section.

Answer (score 1):

Open a messagebox and read the result like so:

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(
    "Text", 
    "Title", 
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
    MessageBoxIcon.Question);

if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //The user clicked 'Yes'
}
else if (result == DialogResult.No)
{
    //The user clicked 'No'
}
else
{
    //If the user somehow didn't click 'Yes' or 'No'
}
```